# How long would it take to get residence permit in UK

Tags: immigration, resident-permit, uk-visa, uk-citizens, uk-citizenship

I will be moving to the UK in August with Tier 2 long term visa. I'm an Indian passport holder. How long would it take for me to get a residence permit?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by a residence permit? Do you mean a [BRP](https://www.gov.uk/biometric-residence-permits/need-brp), which essentially is your visa, or an [FLR/ILR](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/permanent-residence-card) resident card?